# Error while creating EC2 Dynamic Inventory in Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, boto

I am new to Ansible. I had been using the following tutorial to set up dynamic inventory- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/getting-started-with-ansible-and-dynamic-amazon-ec2-inventory-management/

While running ec2.py, I am getting the following error-
**ERROR: Inventory script (ec2.py) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/ansible/ec2.py", line 130, in 
    from boto import elasticache
ImportError: cannot import name elasticache**

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to install the boto module

```
pip install boto
```

should do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu (at least on 12.04), it appears that if you install python modules via PIP, **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages** will not readable to other - it will just be readable to root user and staff group

```
drwxr-s---  6 root staff  4096 Jan  7 22:04 awscli
drwxr-s---  2 root staff  4096 Jan  7 22:04 awscli-1.9.17.dist-info
drwxr-s---  6 root staff  4096 Dec 28 22:07 beaver
drwxr-s---  2 root staff  4096 Dec 28 22:07 Beaver-31-py2.7.egg-info
drwxr-s--- 57 root staff  4096 Dec 28 22:07 boto
drwxr-s---  2 root staff  4096 Dec 28 22:07 boto-2.38.0.dist-info
drwxr-s---  5 root staff  4096 Jan  7 21:54 botocore
drwxr-s---  2 root staff  4096 Jan  7 21:54 botocore-1.3.17.dist-info
```

The simplest solution would be (without making permission changes to dist directory) is to add your user to staff group:

```
usermod -aG staff USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

if you install Ansible from Ansible ppa

```
https://launchpad.net/~ansible/+archive/ubuntu/ansible
```

then your Ansible is installed using the python 2.7 package in your Ubuntu.

you will need python-boto installed, you have two ways to do this:

1. install the `python-boto` package in your Ubuntu system:

   `sudo apt-get install python-boto`
2. install the package `boto` using pip in your system python, **NOT RECOMMENDED**, avoid this because you will have future conflicts between python packages installed from apt as dependencies and packages installed with `pip`

   `sudo pip install boto`

Answer (score -1):

Hello All I"m running in to this same issue.  My Set up is as the following:

- Mac OSX 10.11.6
- Python 2.7.13
- Ansible 2.3.0.0
- boto 2.46.1

I'am running homebrew, and I have tried reinstalling both ansible and boto with no luck.  I keep receiving the error message:

`ERROR! Attempted to execute "inventories/ec2.py" as inventory script: Inventory script (inventories/ec2.py) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Sites/admin/ansible/inventories/ec2.py", line 130, in <module>
    from boto import elasticache
ImportError: cannot import name elasticache`

Looking for any assistance.  Thank you!

Comment: Figured it out.  Boto was installed in the root user and not my user.  To resolve run: `pip install --user boto`.

Comment: I flagged -1 because you used answers for putting your question, this section is to answer the question